# UnityWebRequestAssetBundle load assetbundle is null

Tags: unity-game-engine

i`m sure the path is correct, and i debug at vs show the obj is null
but it will show the ab in immediate window if i input

```c#
ab.LoadAsset<BaseUI>(BundlePaths.Paths[assetsName].assetsPath)
```

`T` is `BaseUI`,why `obj` is `null`? debug is not `null`?

```c#
public static IEnumerator LoadAssets<T>(string assetsName) where T : Object
{
   using (var ur = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(BundlePaths.Paths[assetsName].filePath))
   {
      yield return ur.SendWebRequest();
      var ab = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(ur);
      yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
      var obj = ab.LoadAsset<T>(BundlePaths.Paths[assetsName].assetsPath);
      Debug.Log(obj.name);
   }  
}
```

Comment: if i change T to GameObject. it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depricated!

From [`AssetBundle.LoadAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAsset.html)

> Prior to version 5.0, users could fetch individual components directly using Load. **This is not supported anymore**. Instead, please use `LoadAsset` to load the `GameObject` first and then look up the component on the object.

---

The way to go now seems to be something maybe like

```c#
var gObj = ab.LoadAsset<GameObject>(BundlePaths.Paths[assetsName].assetsPath);

if(typeof(T) == typeof(GameObject))
{
    Debug.Log(gObj.name);
}
else
{
    obj = gObj.GetComponent<T>();
    if(!obj) 
    {
        Debug.LogError($"{0} doesn't have a component {1}", gObj.name, typeof(T));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(obj.name);
    }
}
```